# Can I retrieve Ansible inventory without writing a file parser?

Tags: ruby, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm working on a wrapper for our Ansible scripts in Ruby -- I'm trying to get the host list defined in our `inventory/product` files though, and can't find a way to do this without writing a custom parser for ansible formatted inventory files. Is there an API or just an ansible command I could run within ruby to get this hostlist?

Comment: Since it's in a standard format, why not use [an existing parser](https://github.com/twp/inifile)?

Comment: Does this handle cases such as `[dev:children]`?

Comment: Give it a shot and see how it works out. I think Ansible's notation is not a standard feature, but the file format itself is very standardized. Ansible is written in Python as far as I know, so unless someone's already written a Ruby handler, you may have to do a little work to get that going yourself. Doesn't seem too challenging, mind you, once you have the raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just need the list of inventory hosts (and not any of the other info), you can do:

```
ansible all -i (your inventory file here) --list-hosts
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for